# Is ZFC + classes equi-interpretable with MK?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

If we add to the language of **ZFC** class symbols, denoted using letter style $``\mathcal X, \mathcal Q, \mathcal R, \mathcal P, \mathcal L,.."$, call it *class style*, then add the axiom schema of **class comprehension**: $$\exists \mathcal X \forall \mathcal Y \ [\mathcal Y \in \mathcal X \leftrightarrow \exists y=\mathcal Y :\phi(y)]$$,
Where $\phi(y)$ is any formula in which $y$ only occur free and in which $\mathcal X$ doesn't occur.

Add all axioms of **ZFC** written in non-class style.

Add the axiom of **sorting**: $$\forall x \exists \mathcal Y (x= \mathcal Y)$$
Add the axiom of **membership**: $$\forall x \forall \mathcal Y (\mathcal Y \in x \to \exists y (y=\mathcal Y))$$

Call the resulting theory "**ZFC** + *classes*".

Notice that **ZFC** + *classes* is different from **NBG\MK** where every member of a class is a set, here only members of sets are sets, so you can have *proper classes* (i.e. non-sets) that are members of proper classes.

> Is **ZFC** + *classes* equi-interpretable with **MK**?

If instead of adding **ZFC** axioms in non-class style only, we add all homogeneously written axioms of **ZFC**.

Where in a homogeneous expression either *all* terms are written in *non-class* style or *all* terms are written in *class* style.

Call the resulting theory **ZFC**+$classes_2$

> Is **ZFC**+$classes_2$ consistent?
>
> If consistent, then what's its consistency strength?

To be noticed is that if **ZFC**+$classes_2$ is not stronger than ZFC, then it would be a candidate theory for foundation of mathematics according to [Muller's](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF) criteria!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZFC+2 is equiconsistent with ZFC. Let LZFC be the theory obtained from ZFC by adding a constant symbol , an axiom asserting that  is an ordinal, and for every formula F of ZF with parameters from  an axiom asserting that F holds in  iff F holds. By reflection one can see that LZFC is a conservative extension of ZFC. If we interpret set as an element of , and everything as a class, then all the axioms of ZFC+2 hold.

Comment: can a similar argument prove the same result for **ZFC** + $classes_2$? Something similar to $V_\alpha \prec V $

Comment: @Zuhair: Yes and I have edited the answer to indicate this.

Comment: when you said "by reflection", which reflection theorem of ZFC you are using?